# Check primality of large prime by Miller-Rabin

Tags: primality-test

I need to check whether $7150309735704750359$ is prime. Naive methods, Sieve algorithm and AKS didn't work. So I tried Miller-Rabin. Now it says [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Deterministic_variants_of_the_test) that checking for some small set of $a$ is enough. But the data given are for numbers smaller than my number. So what do I do?

Comment: *So what do I do?* - You use [this](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean when you say these other methods "didn't work".  Certainly AKS should work.  In any event, "converse of Fermat's theorem" methods based on the factorization of n-1 succeed pretty easily.    Hint:  n-1 = 2*55621277*64276749127.

Comment: By 'didn't work' I meant not within reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

This is a small enough number (less than 2^64) that a large number of tools on the web will easily work.  Things like Pari/GP, Python's numpy, Perl's Math::Prime::Util, etc.  Web pages like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) (use IsPrime[]), the [MPU test web page](http://sti15.com/nt/primality.cgi), or [Alpertron](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) to name some.

No surprise AKS is taking too long.  It will work, but most implementations are horrendously slow (as compared to the fast implementations, which are just glacial -- taking almost 8 seconds for this simple number).

For Miller-Rabin, see [Best Known SPRP Base Sets](http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/) for a list of bases that can be used.  Unfortunately the Wikipedia page insists on listing the best sets from 1993, with only a small footnote pointing to results discovered later.